# List out all audio devices in react native application

Tags: android, ios, react-native, amazon-chime

I am working on a project where I am stuck on figuring out if there is a way we can simply list out all audio devices connected with the phone and then provide users an option to select one from the list. Really not able to figure out how we can achieve that . Also pretty new to react native so don't have such experience too. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a requirement to play audio via that device?

Comment: yes, as of now running a simulator using xcode